# How to get the target class name from a generic instance?

Tags: typescript

I have a generic service which saves data into a remote backend.

It can be generic because for each of my frontend entities (User, Group, ...) there is an endpoint "/api/user", "/api/group", so I can use the following method with success.

```
save<T extends Object>(clazz: { new(): T }, entity: T) {
    return fetch("/api/" + clazz.name.toLocaleLowerCase(),
      { body: JSON.stringify(entity)}
})
```

As you see the method take 2 parameters, the class and an instance of the class. I call it as following:

```
backendService.save(User, new User('Fractaliste'))
```

My question is: can I remove the first parameter? It is only used to extract the classname to build the api path.
Can I extract the classname from the second parameter `entity : T`?

```
class TestClass {}
const x = new TestClass();


function save<T>(clazz: { new(): T }, entity: T) {

    console.log("From entity ", Object.getPrototypeOf(entity).constructor.name);
    console....
```

#### EDIT:

I test following code from @H.B. answer:

```
save<T>(clazz: { new(): T }, entity: T) {

    console.log("From entity ", Object.getPrototypeOf(entity).constructor.name);
    console.log("From clazz ", clazz.name);
}
```

And it gives to me:

[image]

Whereas from [this official playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.3.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8C%20BYAUMAPYB2y0AHtALzQnwDuciq6EAFAJQDcBf%20AMwCuJYEgCWpaBDAA3eAB5YAPnagwALw0AuLHUZddsaNgA00eCQlIAnkc5Z%200Z9GJkiIeADoQRAObsAEQAYgBORAC2FlbittCB5gDyAEYAVvBiXn7wSAAK4UhEtgAO8IkC7JbWNpxebsihQmJEoV4kYBHwPAQurqQQHt6%20ASHhUepa8eYTGm0dXbz4PSb8BDLy7AjIaJAQ5hScQA) it should work... Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could use `constructor.name`.

```js
class TestClass {}
const x = new TestClass();
console.log(x.constructor.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it should work as I confirm it on [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.3.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8C+BYAUMAPYB2y0AHtALzQnwDuciq6EAFAJQDcBf+AMwCuJYEgCWpaBDAA3eAB5YAPnagwALw0AuLHUZddsaNgA00eCQlIAnkc5Z+0Z9GJkiIeADoQRAObsAEQAYgBORAC2FlbittCB5gDyAEYAVvBiXn7wSAAK4UhEtgAO8IkC7JbWNpxebsihQmJEoV4kYBHwPAQurqQQHt6+ASHhUepa8eYTGm0dXbz4PSb8BDLy7AjIaJAQ5hScQA), but the same into my project give me an "Object" class name... I edit my question to add these details, but maybe it's the beginning of a new problem...

Comment: @Fractaliste: I think the correct way might be to access `constructor` on the instance itself.  If the issue is still there, you might need to change the compiler settings somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately when you have a generic parameter, typescript don't let you access the constructor on the `arg T` parameter

Comment: @Fractaliste You can restrict the generic parameter like this: `T extends object`